# Insert items from cart to database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, cart, checkout

I have created a cart. I can successfully add items to my cart but I don't know how to insert them on my database table.
I'm having mental breakdowns now because I don't know what I would do. Someone, please help me huhu.

**This is the code to add items to cart**

```
case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
          $pid=$_GET["pid"];
          $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comms_info WHERE id='$pid'");
                while($commCode=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  $itemArray = array($commCode["code"]=> array('comm_type'=>$commCode["comm_type"], 
                        'code'=>$commCode["code"], 
                        'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 
                        'price'=>$commCode["price"], 
                        'comm_desc'=>$commCode["comm_desc"],
                        //'add_char'=>$commCode["add_char"],
                        //'add_bg'=>$commCode["add_bg"],
                        'add_char'=>$_POST["add_char"],
                        'add_bg'=>$_POST["add_bg"],
                        'image'=>$commCode["image"]));

                  if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    if(in_array($commCode["code"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                      foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                          if($commCode["code"] == $k) {
                            if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                              $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                            }
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
                          }
                      }
                    } else {
                      $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                    }
                  }  else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
                  }
                }
      }
      break;
```

but from there I don't know now what's next. please help me huhuhuhu.

Comment: With SQL queries, aka INSERT INTO.. ?

Comment: yes @LarsStegelitz

Comment: Well, then.. what's the actual problem?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Im trying to do the "insert into" the items of the cart to the database but I don't know know how. everything I searched didn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: I can provide more of my code, I just really don't know how to do the INSERT INTO .. I'm really having a mental breakdown just because of this T^T

Comment: You ask for help about SQL and don't even show one single line of database/SQL related code? Have you done tutorials? If not - why not? Why didn't you asked this in particular?